# How do I patch a buildroot recipe?

Tags: patch, buildroot

I followed the directions in the buildroot documentation but I think they may be wrong.  My patch never gets applied.

To be clear, I am not trying to patch files in the "output" directory, which is what I think the directions are describing.  I'm trying to patch files in the "package" directory to fix a problem with one of their recipes.

Does build root not allow patching of buildroot during the build?  Or is there some trick to it?

Or do I just need to write a script that will apply the patch before running make?

Also, there is no error generated when building the package in question, during the patch step.  Should there be one if the patch is malformed or not appliable?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just as you discovered, patching in Buildroot (as well as any other build system), does refer to patching the source code of a particular application. (In this case files unpacked somewhere under output/build).

If you need to fix something in how Buildroot builds a certain package, you'll need to manually patch the packages .mk and Config.in (possibly adding patches etc). I'd recommend you to create a local branch, and do your work there. This will allow you to easily merge in updates from the main Buildroot tree.

If you're fixing build issues or something else that might be of interest to others, please submit the patch to the Buildroot mailing list.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  It should be made more clear in the manual, f the use case.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear. From the manual "Chapter 18. Patching a package

While integrating a new package or updating an existing one, it may be necessary to patch the source of the software to get it cross-built within Buildroot.
" How would you like to rephrase it? Care to submit a patch for the documentation?